# How to get driving distance between two points in Python

Tags: python, openstreetmap, shapely

Using Python, I'm working with a dataset of taxi trips, and each row is a trip completed. The related columns here are the `trip miles` (trip distance), `pickup_location` and `dropoff_location`. The pick up and drop off locations are represented as `Multipolygon`s.

What I have done is I pick a random point in `pickup_location` and a random point in `dropoff_location`, but the challenge I'm facing is how to find two points with **driving distance** that satisfy:

```
abs(trip miles - distance(start_point, end_point)) <= 0.0005
```

or

```
diff = abs(trip miles - distance(start_point, end_point))/trip miles
```

I have tried `haversine` and `geopy`, but I don't think they provide me with the driving distance that I need. Since this is for educational goals, I can't use Google maps services because they are not free nor cheap.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: What's your specific question ?

Comment: I need to find the driving distance in miles or km between two points using Python. Sorry if it was not clear in the question.

Comment: ... both points need to be present in both Multipolygons ?

Comment: yes. But even though I already have code that makes sure those points are actually in both Multipolygons, I'm open for any solution/suggestions.

Comment: Are we talking about "trip distance" or "linear distance"? If it's "trip", we need the driven path.

Comment: I need the "trip distance", any suggestions?

Comment: Try open street maps. Asking for recommended services or apis is not allowed on SO. There’s no algorithmic way to do this. You need to use a directions service. It might not be free. Most cloud providers have a free tier that would cover most educational use cases.

Comment: thank you for your comment, I contacted google maps explaining to them this is for educational purposes and still waiting to hear from them. What other services can I use beside google maps and open street map?